# Pytorch transform.ToTensor() changes image

Tags: python, pytorch, python-imaging-library, data-science

I want to convert images to tensor using `torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()`, after processing I printed the image but the image became so weird. Here is my code:

```
trans = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor()])

demo = Image.open(img) 
demo_img = trans(demo)
demo_array = demo_img.numpy()*255
print(Image.fromarray(demo_array.astype(np.uint8)))
```

The original image is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2aiK.jpg)

But after processing it is showed like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnYAt.png)

Did I write something wrong or miss something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that the problem is with the channel axis.

If you look at `torchvision.transforms` docs, especially on [`ToTensor()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/transforms/transforms.html#ToTensor)

> Converts a PIL Image or numpy.ndarray (H x W x C) in the range
> [0, 255] to a torch.FloatTensor of shape (C x H x W) in the range [0.0, 1.0]

So once you perform the transformation and return to `numpy.array` your shape is: (C, H, W) and you should change the positions, you can do the following:

```
demo_array = np.moveaxis(demo_img.numpy()*255, 0, -1)
```

This will transform the array to shape (H, W, C) and then when you return to PIL and show it will be the same image.

So in total:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms

trans = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])

demo = Image.open(img) 
demo_img = trans(demo)
demo_array = np.moveaxis(demo_img.numpy()*255, 0, -1)
print(Image.fromarray(demo_array.astype(np.uint8)))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I tried (demo_img.numpy()*255).reshape(96,96,3) before but it didn't work, do you know the reason? numpy can't recognize the pixels?

Comment: @Lance4129 What was the output when you tried to reshape? I suspect that it just scrumbbled the values